# I want to merge 4 rows to form 1 row with 4 sub-rows in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

[This is my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMWUn.png)

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
df1['quarter'].str.contains('/^[-+](20)$/', re.IGNORECASE).groupby(df1['quarter'])
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your question (code) here.

Comment: Please consider adding a reproducible pandas example next time - like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the forum! If I understood your question correctly, you want to form groups per year?

Of course, you can simply do a group by per year as you already have the column.

Assuming you didn't have the year column, you can simply group by the whole string **except** the last 2 characters of the quarter column. Like this (I created a toy dataset for the answer):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'quarter' : pd.Series(['1947q1', '1947q2', '1947q3', '1947q4','1948q1']), 
 'some_value' : pd.Series([1,3,2,4,5])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

This is our toy dataframe:

```
quarter     some_value
0   1947q1  1
1   1947q2  3
2   1947q3  2
3   1947q4  4
4   1948q1  5
```

Now we simply group by the year, but we substract the last 2 characters:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df.quarter.str[:-2])

for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(group, '\n')
```

Output:

```
1947
  quarter  some_value
0  1947q1           1
1  1947q2           3
2  1947q3           2
3  1947q4           4 

1948
  quarter  some_value
4  1948q1           5
```

Additional comment: I used an operation that you can always apply to strings. Check this, for example:

```
s = 'Hi there, Dhruv!'

#Prints the first 2 characters of the string
print(s[:2])
#Output: "Hi"


#Prints everything after the third character
print(s[3:])
#Output: "there, Dhruv!"

#Prints the text between the 10th and the 15th character
print(s[10:15])
#Output: "Dhruv"
```